# SIGNAL / SLOT with two qml files. SLOT will not execute

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

I have two qml files. I would connect a signal with javascript of the one qml file with a slot of the other qml file, but it seems not to work. The slot in the second file will not execute.

Here I connect the signal with the slot (in **main.qml**, GridLayout, onComplete):

```
    var component = Qt.createComponent("Field.qml")
    for (var i=0; i<30; i++) {
        var object = component.createObject(mainGridLayout);
        object.boardX = i % 5;
        object.boardY = i / 5;
        object.board = gameboard;

        gameboard.fieldChanged.connect(object.fieldChange);  //<-- Connect
    }
```

Here I defined the signal (in **main.qml**):

```
    Gameboard {
        id: gameboard
        signal fieldChanged(int x, int y, int val) //<-- Signal defined here

        onBoardFieldChanged: {  //<-- Works fine from C++
            fieldChanged(x,y,value);
        }
    }
```

Here I defined the slot (in **Field.qml**):

```
    function fieldChange(x, y, val){  //<-- Slot method
        if (boardX==x && boardY == y) caption.text = val;
    }
```

There are no errors in the console, but the slot did not execute. What did I do wrong? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I was a bit stupid. The code I posted is correct and works well. The problem was, that the signal was emitted before it was connected to the slot.